# Transformar div em string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como transformar uma div  em uma string?Segue o exemplo de como desejo que fique:

`<div class="teste">oi</div>`

em:

```
"<div class="teste">oi</div>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar [**`Element.outerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML). Exemplo:

```js
var toString = document.getElementById('foo').outerHTML;
alert(toString);
```

```html
<div id='foo' class='bar' data-baz='2015'>StackOverflow</div>
```